# Delete Property Of Realm Object in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

I am using Realm as an offline DB with a RN application and am trying to delete a property of a Realm Object.

I feel like this is a simple task that I am approaching in the wrong way. My schema name is article, so in my code I attempt to delete the schema property with `Article.properties` which throws an error `Object type "Article.properties" not found in schema`. Code below:

```
class Article {}
Article.schema = {
  name: 'Article',
  properties: {title: 'string'}
};

let realm = new Realm({schema: [Article]});
let favs = realm.objects('Article.properties')

deleteBookmarkItem () {
  let itemToDelete = (favs)
  realm.write(() => {
    realm.delete(itemToDelete)
  })
}
```

So, how can i access the properties of my Realm object?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This statement `let favs = realm.objects('Article.properties')` tries to fetch all objects of type "Article.properties" with doesn't exist. You should remove the `.properties` part. Also, it gives you a list of objects -- is it your intention to delete all of them? If so, you should iterate through it, or otherwise perhaps just delete the first one with `let itemToDelete = favs[0]`

Comment: What do you want to delete ? The entire object or just have a blank title ?

Comment: Yeh @Ludovic I guess I need to re-structure my schema. I basically want a Article schema full of Articles, and on  `realm.delete` delete the entire article. How would you suggest I structure the schema to be able to delete it properly? Thanks for your help.